# Can we use synchronization on class in java?

Tags: java

I have seen that we use synchronization on methods and block in java. But I have a doubt whether can we synchronize a class in java? If yes, then what is the use of synchronizing a class.

Comment: Define what you mean by "synchronization on a class", for now it looks like you may be looking for `synchronized(YourClass.class){...}`.

Comment: This code shows synchronization of a block .. not a "Synchronized Class".

Comment: @ErstwhileIII If you are referring to my comment then consider adding `@Pshemo` before it to be explicit (for now it looks like your comment is for OP, which kind of doesn't make sense because there is no code in the question). If that is the case then you may or may not be right because as currently written this question is unclear and we can't know what OP wants: IMHO "synchronized class" is little different than "synchronization ON class".

Comment: Actually, "synchronized class" or "synchronized instance" is meaningless as a precise term in Java.  I suppose one either must say it's meaningless or take it as shorthand for "synchronize on".

Answer (score 2):

Yes why not. You can manually do that or automatically happens that only when you synchronized static members of a class.

In Manual case

```
synchronized(Example.class) {

}
```

System puts lock on class when you do

```
public static synchronized void example() {
```

Comment: Though it must be remembered that the `synchronized` statement/keyword *only* synchronizes operations within the following `{}`.  It does not magically make all operations against the object synchronized or "thread safe".

Comment: Hi Thnks for the answer. I guess this is something like class level lock

Comment: I would appreciate if have an example on this

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can  write

```
public static doSomeThing(){
    synchonized(xxxx.class){
        ......;
    } 
}
```

or

```
public static synchonized doSomtThing(){
    ......;
}
```

These two methods are same,because they all use the object of a class to be a lock;

Answer (score -3):

No .. there is no concept of a "Synchronized Class" in Java. You may want to read reference to concurrency [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) from Oracle.  You may create a synchronized block (and reference a class in that blocking statement ... though I am not sure why you would want to do this).

Comment: From the docs you mentined [A Synchronized Class Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html)

Comment: The example you reference shows how to use synchronization IN a class, not "on" a class (as part of the class definition).